# I switched from yolov5 to yolov8 and cant find specific documentation on printing coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, yolov5, yolov8

Yolo v5 let me use `results.xyxy[0].tolist()` and let me use the results `[x1, x2, y1, y2, confidence, object]`. However, switching to yolov8 no longer lets me do this and gives me this error: `*AttributeError: 'Results' object has no attribute 'xyxy'*`. How can I fix this?

yolov5 code:

```
import mss as mss
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
import win32api
import pyautogui
import time

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)
scc = mss()
monitor = {'top': 360, 'left': 640, 'width': 640, 'height': 360}

while True:
    img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
    results = model(img)
    rl = results.xyxy[0].tolist()
    if len(rl) > 0:
        if rl[0][4] > .35:
            if rl[0][5] == 0:
                doSomething()
```

yolov8 code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
from mss import mss
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import win32api

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
sct = mss()
monitor = {'top': 360, 'left': 640, 'width': 640, 'height': 360}

while True:
    img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (640, 360), sct.grab(monitor).rgb)
    screen = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    results = model(screen)
    rl = results.xyxy[0].tolist()
    if len(rl) > 0:
        if rl[0][4] > .35:
            if rl[0][5] == 0:
                doSomething()
```

I tried printing the results[0].boxes but it printed in a format with thousands of numbers that I couldn't understand or utilize.

Comment: there are some changes between v5 and v8 but reading documentation you could check conditionally the prediction confidence by defining 
`boxes = results[0].boxes` and `boxes.conf / boxes.cls` i think it should be enough to replace the whole code removing `if len(rl)>0`.